# How to read a json file into html table php?

Tags: php, html, css, json

Okay so this is my first time posting on this website. I need a little help, I am trying to add data from a json API into a html table. This is what I have so far.

```
<?php

$gamertag = 'x0--ii';
$jsonurl = 'https://tusticles.com/psn/api?psn='.$gamertag;
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
var_dump(json_decode($json));

<?
```

Here is my Output:

`object(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["status"]=> string(3) "200" ["response"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (5) { ["onlineId"]=> string(6) "x0--II" ["avatar"]=> string(77) "http://static-resource.np.community.playstation.net/avatar_m/SCEI/I0053_m.png" ["plus"]=> int(0) ["aboutMe"]=> string(0) "" ["trophies"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (6) { ["trophyLevel"]=> int(3) ["progress"]=> int(7) ["platinum"]=> int(0) ["gold"]=> int(2) ["silver"]=> int(6) ["bronze"]=> int(19) } } }`

I want to display the image as well as all the values. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Once you decode the json, it's a data structure like any other in PHP. You access data in the structure exactly the same way as any other structure.

Comment: Yup, use `json_decode($json, true)` if you want to access it like an array. Otherwise you'll need to use `->` for properties. The images you just wrap around `<img src="` `">` tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$gamertag = 'x0--ii';
$jsonurl = 'https://tusticles.com/psn/api?psn='.$gamertag;
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
#var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

/* json formatted for readability
object(stdClass)#1 (2) { 
    ["status"]=> string(3) "200" 
    ["response"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (5) { // response is an array()
        ["onlineId"]=> string(6) "x0--II" 
        ["avatar"]=> string(77) "http://static-resource.np.community.playstation.net/avatar_m/SCEI/I0053_m.png" 
        ["plus"]=> int(0) 
        ["aboutMe"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["trophies"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (6) { // trophies is an array()
            ["trophyLevel"]=> int(3) 
            ["progress"]=> int(7) 
            ["platinum"]=> int(0) 
            ["gold"]=> int(2) 
            ["silver"]=> int(6) 
            ["bronze"]=> int(19) 
        } 

    }

}
*/

$json = json_decode($json, true);
$rsp = $json['response']; // response array
$trophies = $rsp['trophies']; // trophy array

// examples
$avatar = $rsp['avatar'];
$onlineId = $rsp['onlineId'];
$trophylevel = $trophies['trophyLevel'];

// inline html example
echo("<div><img src=\"".$rsp['avatar']."\" /></div>");
// or
echo("<div><img src=\"".$json['response']['avatar']."\" /></div>");

echo("<div>".$json['trophies']['progress']."</div>");
// or
echo("<div>".$json['response']['trophies']['progress']."</div>");
?>
```

Comment: $trophies = $rsp['trophies']; is an array. use $trophies['progress'] , $trophies['platinum'] etc. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would put the json_decode data into a PHP variable, and access it like a normal PHP object array

Here's a quick example:

```
<?php

$gamertag = 'x0--ii';
$jsonurl = 'https://tusticles.com/psn/api?psn='.$gamertag;
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
$content = json_decode($json);

echo "ID: ".$content->response->onlineId."<br />";
echo '<img src="'.$content->response->avatar.'" />';

echo "<table border=1>";
foreach ($content->response->trophies as $key => $value){
    echo "<tr>
            <td>".$key."</td>
            <td>".$value."</td>
        </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

That would loop through your trophies put it into an HTML table.